# Override browser shortcut keys while using angular jshotkeys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hotkeys

I am using angular hotkeys for handling shortcut using keyboard on my web page. But now i want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save my data. But when i try it shows web page save dialog.
So, is there any way to override it in hotkeys framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [this framework](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/blob/master/src/hotkeys.js), you can probably just cancel the default effects of the associated event:

```
  hotkeys.add({
      combo: 'ctrl+s',
      description: 'Save my data',
      allowIn: ['INPUT', 'SELECT', 'TEXTAREA'],
      callback: function(event) {
          // (insert saving logic here)
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
```

Comment: I have textbox and i typed something, and press ctrl+s then it is not working. After blur from textbox it is working.

Comment: Ah yes, you need the `allowIn` option. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Spiny